# Renaming files in a folder by extracting the first part of file name and extension (R programming)

Tags: r

I have hundreds of files that contain data from Yahoo finance API.

They are named in the following form:

```
R> print(list.files())
  [1] "A_yahoo_2017-10-14_2018-10-14.csv"
  [2] "AAL_yahoo_2017-10-14_2018-10-14.csv"
  [3] "AAP_yahoo_2017-10-14_2018-10-14.csv"
```

I want to remove the name that comes after the ticker(symbol) and keep the extension.

So for example:

```
[2] "AAL_yahoo_2017-10-14_2018-10-14.csv"
```

becomes

```
[2] "AAL.csv"
```

I decided to remove the extension, split the entire name of the file, take the ticker and add the extension again (tedious I know). So something like this:

```
library(tools)
oldnames = list.files()
oldnames = tools::file_path_sans_ext(oldnames)
oldnames = strsplit(oldnames, "_")
```

Which would yield something like this (example)

```
print(oldnames)
.
.
[[173]]
[1] "EXC"        "yahoo"      "2017-10-14" "2018-10-14"
.
.
```

As you can see the ticker is at [1]. I am unsure how next to proceed to rename the entire files in the folder or if there is a more parsimonious method of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### setting up the test case

```
fn <- c("A_yahoo_2017-10-14_2018-10-14.csv"
, "AAL_yahoo_2017-10-14_2018-10-14.csv"
, "AAP_yahoo_2017-10-14_2018-10-14.csv")
```

#### solution

```
firstpart <- sapply(strsplit(fn,"_"), "[[",1)
mapply(file.rename, from=fn, to=paste0(firstpart, ".csv"))
```

But you have to make sure the first parts are unique, i.e. there is just one filename starting with AAL, AAP, etc.